# Configuring Amazon Linux authenticate to LDAP server

Tags: openldap

I was wondering if anyone had success in configuring Amazon Linux to authenticate to an LDAP server?

**EDIT:**
For more information on what I have done:

I disabled anonymous access on my OpenLDAP server, so I am trying to have my openldap client on Amazon Linux connect to the OpenLDAP server with a `binddn` to authenticate. But when I check the logs on the OpenLDAP server, the `binddn` is empty. I have added my `binddn` and `bindpw` to /etc/pam_ldap.conf.

Part of my `/etc/nsswitch.conf`

```
passwd:     files ldap
shadow:     files ldap
group:      files ldap
```

my `/etc/pam_ldap.conf`

```
base dc=example,dc=com
bindnd uid=test_client,ou=System,dc=example,dc=com
bindpw secret
scope sub
pam password md5

nss_base_passwd ou=System,dc=example,dc=com?one
nss_base_passwd ou=People,dc=example,dc=com?one
nss_base_shadow ou=People,dc=example,dc=com?one
nss_base_shadow ou=System,dc=example,dc=com?one

tls_checkpeer no
uri ldap://ec2-00-00-00-00.compute.amazonaws.com
ssl no
tls_cacertdir /etc/openldap/cacerts
```

Comment: I haven't tried, but I don't see why not..  What've you tried?  If you post what you've tried, I'll throw together an EC2 instance and have a go..

Comment: I've used authconfig-tui and selected `use ldap` and `Use LDAP Authentication`. And then I tried to add my binddn to /etc/pam_ldap.conf but when I try to ssh into the Amazon Linux machine with a uid in my LDAP server, the LDAP server receives a blank binddn. And I disabled anonymous binding and required authc on my LDAP server

Comment: Can you post some bits of your config? /etc/nsswitch.conf, /etc/ldap.conf, /etc/ldap/ldap.conf and /etc/pam.d/common-*

Comment: I don't have /etc/ldap.conf, but have /etc/pam_ldap.conf. And I changed some of the values to protect my privacy.

Comment: I was using LDAP authentication with autofs for at least 7 years in Amazon cloud. I will check my notes and will post it here once I get home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by configuring `/etc/nslcd.conf` with my `binddn` and `bindpw`